# php file saved via move_file_upload works when called directly not via exec()

Tags: php, file-upload, error-handling

This is the dilemma. I have a script that works perfectly for writing small video files into S3 bucket and local docker.
I need to update the script so it can handle larger files. In order to do that I am using the exec() method in which I run a php script to upload the file so it runs it in the background. This is the code I'm using:

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['form-file-input']['tmp_name'][$i];
$directory = $config['content_directory'];  
echo (is_file($tempFile) ? 'Tempfile is a file' : 'Tempfile is not a file');
echo (is_readable($tempFile) ? ' and tempfile is readable.' : ' and tempfile is not readable.');                    
echo '<br>'.'This is the file name: '.$newFileName.'<br>';//already defined 
chdir('/var/www/webApp/_apps/training_videos/');//required to find i-did-it.php - tested and doesn't affect saving functionality                    
exec("php i-did-it.php $tempFile $directory $newFileName 2>&1", $out);                  
var_dump($out);                 
//$resultado = move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $directory . '/_' . 'videos' . '/' . $newFileName);
//var_dump($resultado);
exit;
```

BELOW ARE THE CONTENTS OF i-did-it.php
Note that the code reviews before and after executing if the the param is a readable file and that the other params have a valid value. Also note that I set all errors, set a log file and try to catch the last error.

```
//Set all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('error_log','/var/www/siteContent/logs/log.txt');//verified that log file can be written to
//Get the params
$tempFile = $argv[1];
$directory = $argv[2];
$newFileName = $argv[3];
//Verify that it arrives as a readable file
echo (is_file($tempFile) ? 'Tempfile is a file' : 'Tempfile is not a file');
echo (is_readable($tempFile) ? ' and tempfile is readable.' : ' and tempfile is not readable.');
//Display the params
echo ' Temp file name: '.$tempFile;
echo ', the directory: '.$directory;
echo ' and new file name: '.$newFileName.' *** ';
//Move the file and dump results
$putResult = move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $directory . '/_' . 'videos' . '/' . $newFileName);//original
var_dump($putResult);
print_r(error_get_last());
```

So what is the problem?

move_uploaded_file commmand is not working when called via exec().

Note that if I replace this line

```
exec("php i-did-it.php $tempFile $directory $newFileName 2>&1", $out);
```

with this one

```
$resultado = move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $directory . '/_' . 'videos' . '/' . $newFileName);
```

it works!
Note that it is commented in the first snippet.

[Those are the results I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MNGI.png)

In order to troubleshoot I need to know why the move_uploaded_file command is not working since it only throws true or false. It's known it is false since it doesn't work. I would like to get more errors than that. The method recommended for the task I cannot use since my file is not set like this: `$_FILES['file']` but as a variable (It has to be done that way since I'm passing it as a param) so I cannot check errors towards: `$_FILES['file']['error']`
Reference for the error obtaining approach
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
Following the previous example I tried applying it to the var that holds the file to no avail:

```
if ($tempFile === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
//uploading successfully done
} else {
throw new UploadException($tempFile);
}
```

What do I need to continue?
At this point it would be helpful to know these 2 things:

1. How can I get the error/warning from move_uploaded_file that is coming back as false?
2. Any ideas why move_file_upload will work perfectly fine when called directly but fails when called via `exec("php myfile.php $param1 $param2 $param3 2>&1", $output)`

Comment: did you enable exec function in php.ini?

Comment: Any other ideas as of how to accomplish handling a large video upload in the background while the control is sent back to the user is another approach that could save the day.

Comment: exec does run the file @jer it gives me results. Please see the image above. Not enough rep points to attach directly. There is a link where it says "Those are my results"

Comment: You can't use `move_uploaded_file()` in the background. Uploaded temp files are automatically deleted when the first script exits.

Comment: How could I accomplish uploading a file in the background?

Comment: PHP via the web browser is not asynchronous, full stop.  If you want to do some UI action in the background, AJAX is probably your best bet.

Comment: But you're not doing anything in the background. You didn't end the shell command with `&`, so it runs synchronously.

Comment: Does the CLI version of `php.ini` have the same value of `upload_tmp_dir` as the web version? `move_uploaded_file()` checks whether the file is in that directory.

Comment: You can just use `rename()` instead of `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: use ajax instead or create an hidden iframe and point it your form to the iframe

Comment: @Barmar rename() did the trick for localhost... going to clean up code and try with S3 bucket.

Comment: As I mentioned before rename() worked saving the file. The issue that I have now is that the operation is not being handled in the background. I did note your comment about the & at the end of my script. I update like this `exec("php i-did-it.php $tempFile $directory $newFileName > /dev/null 2>&1 &", $out);` The process is not being run in the background as expected. Any ideas @Barmar